# Error using [[ ]] and -eq

Tags: bash

Shell script snippet:

```
tagSearch= $(grep '^\#ctags$' ./"$1" | wc -l)
if [[ $tagSearch -ne "0" ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

Results in:

`line 2: /bb/bin/1: Permission denied`

Context:

I'm trying to detect whether a particular pattern exists in a file so I can take a particular action.

I understand the error I'm getting, the detection is working but the script is trying to evaluate the result '1' and run the program '1' in my path. This isn't what I want. How do I get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: That's one of the reasons one should always quote (`"`) variables in expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable assignments in the bash shell should not have a space after the equals. Actually it should never have whitespace in it at all. See below.

```
tagSearch=$(grep '^\#ctags$' "./$1" | wc -l)
if [[ $tagSearch -ne 0 ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

Not important to your error but also of note, when using the [double bracket syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), you don't need to quote that zero any more than the variable you are comparing it with.

Actually your whole code could be re-factored using `grep`'s quite mode and evaluating the return code to see if you got any matches:

```
if grep '^\#ctags$' "./$1"
then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is

```
tagSearch= $(grep '^\#ctags$' ./"$1" | wc -l)
----------^
```

You can't use spaces around the equal sign; what you're actually doing here is to temporarily set `tagSearch` to the empty string in the environment, then invoking `grep '^\#ctags$' ./"$1" | wc -l`, then trying to run that as a command since the `$()` will have inserted the result into the command line.

```
tagSearch=$(grep '^\#ctags$' ./"$1" | wc -l)
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what got executed to cause that specific error.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can have that simpler, because the return code of grep will be 0 if something is found (1 otherwise), so you don't need wc -l. And you can just write:

```
if `grep -q pattern file`; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;
```

Comment: I can't up or accept this because it doesn't really answer the question, but I ended up taking your suggestion and dropping the wc -l and testing the return code instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg: You asked: "How do I get the behavior I'm looking for?" and the if-construction I posted has the behavior you are looking for...